# See server desktop in tightVNC

Tags: networking, remote, vnc, remote-desktop

I installed *tightvncserver* on one Linux machine and *xtightvncviewer* on another Linux machine.

I can connect from client computer to server computer without problems. There are two problems:

1. The screens are different. On the client computer I can see on desktop all the files from my *$HOME* folder.
2. I can't see on server computer what is being done from client computer. Cursor movements, opening files, everything.

I'm using *Ubuntu 11.04* with *Xmonad*. Could the problems 1 and 2 be solved and *tightVNC* will work as *teamviewer*?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you correctly.  Have a look at [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_remote_desktop_software#Terminology), is (1) supposed to mean "*seamless windows*" and (2) "*remote assistance*"?  If so, scrolling up tells you that TightVNC is not able to do (1) but should be able to do (2).

Comment: point 1 means that on the server the desktop is empty because it shows files from *$HOME/desktop* but the client sees files from *$HOME* directory. This difference wouldn't be such problem, but I'd like to see what actions the other person is doing on my computer (problem 2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`tightvnc` is designed to present an independent session.  What you want is something like the [`vnc` server extension for `xorg`](http://xf4vnc.sourceforge.net/modular.html) which exports the running console X11 session via RFB.  It is packaged for a number of Linux distributions (try the `vnc4server` package on Debian or Ubuntu).

The [X11VNC](http://www.karlrunge.com/x11vnc/) package can also do it and is considerably more flexible, although it's also rather complex and initial setup can be bewildering; the website provides some canned recipes for common usages, though.

Comment: I'm using tightVNC because it's multiplatform.

Comment: The VNC protocol is substantially compatible (in particular everyone has picked up the "tight" extensions — and X11vnc is based on the tightvnc codebase, although libvnc is based on the realvnc codebase), so clients remain cross platform.  Your server is Ubuntu, you said; it's *that* that would run X11vnc or libvnc.

Comment: OK, so it's sufficient to install *vnc4server* and tightVNC client from Windows platform will be able to connect to my Ubuntu machine?

Comment: Should be, yes.  Note that you really want some kind of security (VNC protocol itself has none); PuTTY on Windows can tunnel VNC, and the documentation for your client should describe how to do it (last time I checked the Windows TightVNC client docs did).

Comment: I found a simple starter guide for x11vlnc that had me up and running in no time here: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/x11vnc